# Найти количество простых чисел в диапазоне от 0 до 1000. C#

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте!
Задание: Найти количество все простых чисел в диапазоне от 0 до 1000.
Помогите доработать код. Не понимаю чего не хватает.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        int result = 0;

        for (int i = 2; i <= 1000; i++)
        {
            if (i % i == 0 & i / 1 == 0)
            {
                result += 1;
            }

        }
        Console.WriteLine("Простых чисел" + result);


        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Та же проблема: не понимаю что вам в нем не нравится.

Comment: только 0 при делении на 1 вернет 0

Comment: так у вас в итоге выводится только количество чисел, а вы вроде как хотите получить сами числа.. да и само условие странное

Comment: Извиняюсь, неправильно описал задание. Мне нужно количество. В результате выводит 0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Простое число — натуральное (целое положительное) число, имеющее ровно
>   два различных натуральных делителя — единицу и самого себя.

Чтобы программно проверить простое число или нет достаточно проверить не делится ли это число на числа до квадратного корня из этого числа. Если делится - число не простое, в противном случае - простое.

Для определения, является ли число простым напишем метод, который определяет простое число или нет:

```
private static bool IsPrimeNumber(int number)
{
    int sqrtNumber = (int) (Math.Sqrt(number));
    for (int i = 2; i <= sqrtNumber; i++)
    {
        if (number % i == 0)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Теперь собственно говоря сам код, в котором будем вызывать метод:

```
int count = 0;
int maxNumber = 1000;// максимальное число, до которого будем считать (можно менять)
// можно переделать на ввод с клавиатуры

for (int num = 2; i <= maxNumber; num++)
{
    if (IsPrimeNumber(num))
    {
        count++;
        // Console.Write(num.ToString()+","); // можно вывести на экран
    }
}
// Console.WriteLine(); // отступ просто для красоты, если выводим на экран
Console.WriteLine("Количество простых чисел в диапазоне от 0 до " + maxNumber);
Console.WriteLine("Простых чисел: " + count);
```

Результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В Вашем случае условие не правильное. Вот познавательная страница: [Как проверить, является ли число простым](http://ru.wikihow.com/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C,-%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%BC)

Comment: Ой, подскажите как вызывать прогу в консоли вне Эклипса.

Comment: +1, но на английском Prime, а не Simple.

Comment: Думаю, что Вам достаточно запустить исполняемый файл `.exe`, который получился в результате.

Comment: @VladD, спасибо, буду знать.

Comment: вроде не до половины, а до квадратного корня из числа

Comment: @Grundy, точно! Ну я просто немного больше проверяю... Сейчас поправлю

Comment: @Grundy, в целях экономии времени можно еще проверять является ли число четным (с исключением двойки). Но задача стоит не в оптимизации, а в нахождении. 1000 штук - это не много :)

Comment: (int)(Math.Sqrt(number))  будет вызываться многократно для проверки условия, если я не ошибаюсь... Лучше перед циклом вычислить 1 раз и записать в переменную.

Comment: @iluxa1810, тут Вы правы, но есть одно *НО*, на мой взгляд. Не так давно начал читать книгу по рефакторингу Маритана Фаулера, так вот, есть там пункт по поводу внутренних временных переменных. Как оказалось - это не очень хорошо. В данной программе это не сильно влияет на производительность, если уж быть откровенным, то практически никак не влияет, но если чисел будет много, то уж лучше в переменную. Спасибо за подсказку - внесу правку.

Comment: по поводу `&` и `&&` вы не совсем правы. `&&` - используется для сокращенного вычисления операции, т.е. если левый операнд `false` - то правый не вычисляется, аналогично для `||`. В случае с `&` и `|` происходит предварительное вычисление обоих операндов. Но кроме того `&` и `|` являются битовыми операциями, поэтому в смешанных выражениях, где кроме логических операторов используются арифметические и операторы сравнения, крайне желательно ставить скобки для указания приоритета вычислений, либо вызубрить приоритеты операций в языке для составления однозначно вычисляемого выражения.

Comment: @rdorn, написал не подумав. Забыл, что они различаются...думал код не скомпилируется. Но после Вашего комментария вспомнил, что есть просто логический оператор,  а есть укороченный. '&&' - вот он укороченный, как это не странно.

Answer (score 3):

Решение уже написали, тем не менее считаю что в данном случае имеет смысл подробно разобрать ошибку автора.

Итак, исходное условие предложенное автором выглядит так

```
if (i % i == 0 & i / 1 == 0)
```

Разберем его на части:

1. `i % i == 0` 
   Это условие всегда истинно, т.к. остаток от деления любого числа на это же число всегда равен 0.
2. `i / 1 == 0`. 
   Это условие никогда не выполняется, т.к. результат деления любого числа на 1 всегда равен этому числу, но ни как не 0. Можно было бы его исправить на `i % 1 == 0`, но в этом случае условие будет всегда истинно, т.к. Остаток от деления на 1 всегда 0.

В итоге мы получаем либо всегда ложь, если не исправляем второе условие; либо всегда истину, если меняем деление на взятие остатка во втором условии.

> Простое число — натуральное (целое положительное) число, имеющее ровно два различных натуральных делителя — единицу и самого себя.

Надо понимать, проверку что число делится без остатка на себя и 1 пройдет абсолютно любое число, даже не целое. А из определения следует, что нет других чисел на которые можно разделить число без остатка и именно это нужно проверять.

PS: Жаль что приходится объяснять этот довольно простой по сути факт вместо вашего преподавателя математики, и далеко не факт что в этом виноват преподаватель. И учтите. что без хорошего знания математики в программировании делать то в общем нечего, так что восстанавливайте пробелы в математике пока не поздно.

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю есть ли в C# метки для выхода из цикла, но вот решение на Java в лоб:

```
public static void main( String[] args ) {
    int res = 0;
    mark1: for ( int i = 2; i <= 1000; i++ ) {
//        for ( int j = i - 1; j != 1; j-- ) {
          for ( int j = (int)Math.sqrt( i ); j != 1; j-- ) {
            if ( i % j == 0 ) {
                continue mark1;
            }
        }
        res++;
    }
    System.out.println( res );
}
```

Comment: В шарпике есть `goto`.